# Youtube caching on Chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

Does anyone knows a solution to cache YouTube videos on a chrome app ?

I know there are ways to write data and access it later, but i can't find a way to do it with Youtube.
I'm aiming at be able to display those videos Offline or just to consume a small amount of bandwidth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the python command line tool `youtube-dl -g` to get a download URL and store that. However you will not be able to distribute such an application in google's webstore since I'm sure it's against youtube terms of service to download videos for later playback.

Comment: Thank you kzahel, well your solution implies that the video is downloaded, after that, i should put in place a homemade player or a basic html one ? No way to use the Youtube Player right ?

Comment: Yep. BTW I believe Youtube Red (android) allows for offline playback.